# Как автоматически заполнить поля input, для тестирования базы данных и валидации?

Tags: php, javascript, html, веб-программирование, laravel

Для проекта использую много элементов input,  
чтобы *тестировать базу данных* и *валидацию*, 
приходится заполнять все поля вручную. 
Как  *ускорить работу* и  **заполнить поля автоматически** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если в каждом input выставить сразу значение value="ваш текст"

Comment: Да такое возможно но,  База данных принимает  только уникальные значения , и после повторной отправки выдает ошибку

Comment: а если к значению инпута подставить время сервера

<?php
echo"<input value='Ваш текст -date(h.m.s)'></input>";

?>

Comment: да  подставка  времени сервера  это решение